# How do I change NA in df$x when df$y == 1

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a simple data frame read from a csv:

`df <- read.csv("test.csv", na.strings = c("", NA))`

that gives this (I am using R):

```
     x  y
1    a  1
2 <NA>  1
3 <NA>  2
4    a  1
5    b  2
6 <NA>  3
```

I would like to change the NA in df$x to another value based on the value in df$y. Such that, if df$x = NA and df$y = 1, df$x = "p1", if df$x = NA and df$y = 2, df$x = "p2" and so on to look like this:

```
     x  y
1    a  1
2   p1  1
3   p2  2
4    a  1
5    b  2
6   p3  3
```

`df <- df %>% replace_na(list(x = "p1"))`

Lets me change the whole of df$x, but I am unable to find anything that puts a stringent condition on it. It would seem I need to use an ifelse statement but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

`mutate(df, x = ifelse(is.na(x) && y == 1, x == 'p1', x == 'p2'))`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution. It should be noted that those `<NA>` values your are trying to change or stored as character strings so they are not considered NA values (you can verify that with `is.na(df1$x)`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(x == "<NA>" & y == 1, "p1", ifelse(x == "<NA>" & y == 2, 
                                                       "p2", ifelse(x == "<NA>" & y == 3,
                                                                    "p3", x))))

   x y
1  a 1
2 p1 1
3 p2 2
4  a 1
5  b 2
6 p3 3
```

Here is another very concise way for as many replacements as possible:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(glue)

df1 %>%
  mutate(x = str_replace(x, "<NA>", glue::glue("p{y}")))

   x y
1  a 1
2 p1 1
3 p2 2
4  a 1
5  b 2
6 p3 3
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you. I don't know why but even though the values are NA R will print them as <NA> when the df is called. I've altered the code from x == "<NA>" to be "is.na(x)".

Comment: My pleasure, your welcome. I don't know maybe changing  `NA` value in `na.strings = c("", NA)` argument to `<NA>` may help. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @SteveS Just as a note in case you have not been familiar with package `glue`, whatever you put between curly braces `{}` will be evaluated as R code. Here it will retrieve the corresponding value of y in that row.

Comment: This looks great

Comment: That's my pleasure dear @akrun. Everything I suggest, I learned from you and I am forever grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use a simple one-liner

```
df$x <- ifelse(is.na(df$x), paste0('p', df$y), df$x)
#    x y
# 1  1 1
# 2 p1 1
# 3 p2 2
# 4  1 1
# 5  2 2
# 6 p3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below using `replace` + `is.na`

```
transform(
  df,
  x = replace(x, is.na(x), paste0("p", y[is.na(x)]))
)
```

which gives

```
   x y
1  a 1
2 p1 1
3 p2 2
4  a 1
5  b 2
6 p3 3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c("a", NA, NA, "a", "b", NA), y = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but the p values are not sequential. The value is dependant on the value in y. Anoushiravan R below, has the answer.

Comment: @SteveS I think my code works in the same way with Anoushiravan R's code `y[is.na(x)]` is assigned to the places where `x` is `NA`. Maybe you are using my previously written code. You can try my current code.